# subset of array C of set length

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose I have a double array `double myArray[16]` with 16 elements. I want to perform a function on each subset of four elements, i.e. the first subset is `myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2], myArray[3]`, the second is `myArray[4], myArray[5], myArray[6], myArray[7]`, and so on.

I want to pass the subset arrays using a pointer to a `void` function that operates on the subset only and write the values to the addresses passed to the function. If I wanted to use all the elements beginning with `myArray[8]`, I could pass `&myArray[8]` to the function, but I need to pass only a predetermined length (4 in this example).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The function needs to know the length. Either hardcoded or passed as a parameter.

Comment: How does the function know the size of the array? It should probably be taking this information as an argument, so you'd just pass a reference to the starting element (such as `&myArray[8]`) and a size of 4

Comment: Use `void func(double *arr,int subcount)` and call it with (e.g.) `func(&myArray[8],4)`. Or, hardwire the count with `#define SUBCOUNT 4`. The outer for loop would be `for (int i = 0;  i < 16;  i += SUBCOUNT) func(&myArray[i],SUBCOUNT);`

Comment: "*I want to pass the subset arrays using a pointer to a void*" -- Why pointer to void, why not pointer to double?

Comment: The function is a CBLAS function and accepts as arguments the dimensions of the matrix, so I suppose it should work in this case?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. As I mentioned previously, the BLAS routine asks for the dimensions of the matrix described by the array, so I am going to test to make sure it works as expected by only selecting the needed elements.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have a function `void myFunction(double arr[4])`, the C compiler treats this exactly like `void myFunctoin(double *arr).  The array itself is not being passed by value; only a pointer value is passed in, and the array elements are referenced using pointer arithmetic and dereferencing.

In C there's almost no difference between a pointer an an array.  You can't assign to an array, but you can assign to a pointer.  Aside from that they're nearly interchangeable.

```
int array[10];
int *ptr = &array[0];

// All 4 of these do the same thing
array[3] = 5; 
*(array + 3) = 5;
ptr[3] = 5; 
*(ptr + 3) = 5;

// all 4 of these do the same thing too
functionCall(&array[3]); 
functionCall(array + 3);
functionCall(&ptr[3]);
functionCall(ptr + 3);

// this is pretty much the only thing different
printf("sizeof(array)=%d\n", sizeof(array)); // prints sizeof(int)*10
printf("sizeof(ptr)=%d\n", sizeof(ptr)); // prints sizeof(int *)

// and this
ptr = array + 5; // fine
array = array + 5; // will not compile, since you can't assign to arrays.
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow the function to know the length of a passed array, the array needs to carry this information in a separate piece of memory. That is an overhead, and C is designed for zero overhead, so it does not support this.

There are languages that automatically deliver this information (and as a consequence, they are slower).

Your only options are to either hard-code the size of array you want to work with in the function (which could be ok or a very bed idea, depending on your context), or pass it as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use an `array[16]` as if it was an `array[4][4]`?

You can use an `union`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

union set {
    double arr[16];
    double sub[4][4];
};

static void func(void *data) /* Why not double *? */
{
    double *x = data;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", *x++);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    union set x = {.arr = {0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15.}};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        func(&x.sub[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> need to pass only a predetermined length

In C, arrays are continuous. To  operate on elements 0,1,2,3, the function need only receive the address of element 0.  To  operate on elements 8,9,10,11, the function need only receive the address of element 8.  So code does not pass a length of the array, but the address of the base of the subset of the array.

```
#define N 16
#define DELTA 4

void fun(int base, double *a) {
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    printf("%2d %e\n", base + i, a[i]);
  } 
}

double myArray[N];
assert(N%DELTA == 0);
for (int i=0 i<N; i += DELTA) {
  fun(i, &myArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you need to set the size of the array at compile time. It really doesn't like when you dynamically change the length of an array. You should get an exception when compiling the program. For this case you would use a pointer that pointed to a contiguous space in memory and you would use realloc every time you added or removed anything from the array so it would always be contiguous and easily searchable.

However, you are using arrays so we are back to the defined size at compile time. Since you know the size at compile time you should be able to split the array into four or more pieces. If you divide 16 by however many subsets you want and take away 1 (the result needs to be even for this to work) you can address a subset by passing 0 for 0-3, 1 for 4-7, 2 for 8-11 and 3 for 12-16. In code it would look something like this

```
void funciton(int array[16], int subset) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
        array[(subset * 4) + i] = foobar;
    }
}
```